# Display Products from External db in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products

I have a database in which some products and its categories. I would like to create a Magento site using this database with all Magento functionalities. I am using Magento 1.9.x and MySql database. How can I do this? Does anyone have any ideas how I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to export a CSV from the existing database according to Magento's CSV structure. Then import that CSV into Magento through the `System > Import/Export > Import` functionality.

To see the structure you can insert a product in Magento and then export via `System > Import/Export > Export` functionality.

You can find a good documentation of the Import/Export functionality by Vinai Kopp here: http://netzarbeiter.com/media/MagentoImagine/ImportExport.pdf

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for your reply... What will I do if the external db upadate it's product details?Is it possible to do with REST API?

Comment: in that case you have to perform a regular update; you can both choose to schedule an export and import or implement API integration; it's your choice

Comment: But It is not possible to perform regular upadate right... So how can I use REST API in this? I am new to this :(

Comment: I can't explain here how Magento REST API works, please refer to the official documentation and if something doesn't sound clear post a specific question.

Comment: Is it possible to display products in Magento site from external db(non Magento db)

Comment: Yes, you can define an external connection, fetch data and populate a product collection but it's not trivial and I'm on mobile and can't provide an example now

Comment: ok.. But how I will do this? I didnot get any tutorial about this and I am new to Magento REST API :(

Comment: Can anyone  provide rest api example...

Comment: what's wrong with official documentation? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html

Comment: yeah..But I want to call external webservices(REST) from magento... I can't find appropriate tutorial about this..

Comment: I suggest you to use Postman to test REST integration; Postman will also generate code for you: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop - what's more, ask for help to the ones who provide the external web services you need to call; hope it helps.

Comment: I am using Postman to test REST integration... But I don't know how to call web service from magento to display products in Magento store...I am new to webservices...

Comment: IMHO it's something you can't learn in a comment on Stack Exchange. Start by examining how catalog pages work in Magento, look at  `Mage_Catalog_CategoryController` and `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`; but you need to know the fundamentals of Magento framework to do what you need. You may be tempted to touch the core files but it's something I discourage you to do. Learn Magento or hire a Magento professional, don't try to cheat.